# Ionic Angular Component: how to destroy?

Tags: navigation, angular7, ionic4

i have a Ionic 4 application, with angular 7 with a custom component. In this component i have implemented a subscription to an event. When the event is published, i receive the message without problem. If i leave the component and i return in it again, if an event is published i receive the message twice. It seems as the previous instance of the same controller was not destroyed (also if the ngOnDestroy is triggered - i have inserted a console.log).
If i repear this action (leave and return) i receive 3 message, then 4 and so on.

So, my question is: is the component destroyed or it remains in memory?

I excpect that every time i enter in a component i have a new instance and all previous instances are destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar issue while working in my project where number of modals opening were increasing each time I visited the page . It turned out that it was a subscription issue .

What I did there was that we called ngOnDestroy of the child component if it existed from the parent page, (You must be importing the component in some page) each time the parent page was left (ionViewWillLeave) like -

```
@ViewChild(someChildComponent) child;
subscriptions;

ionViewWillEnter() {
    // your initialization goes here
}

ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.subscriptions.unsubscribe;
    if (this.child) {
      this.child.ngOnDestroy();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, You can use ngOnDestroy and ngOnInit of your parent page, but make sure  they are called when you suppose them to be called (Ionic stack pages instead of destroying them and calls ngOnDestroy only if that page is on the top of stack and is then removed from the stack, otherwise it uses it's additional lifecycle hooks when page is left or entered.)

As per your question, it is definitely a subscription issue. I would request you to go through the subscription part and debug it to see if the unsubscribe is called where required or not.

Answer (score 0):

From what you described it sounds like your subscription is independent from the lifecycle of your component.

If you don't unsubscribe from it, it will keep listening and fire everytime it gets a new event. Even if angular removes the old component instance and doesn't use it anymore, the browser will keep it in memory just to be able to provide the context for your event handler.

Did you try to explicitly unsubscribe from the subscription in the ngOnDestroy method?

Comment: In the ngOnDestroy method i do the unsubscription of all events. It seems as the component is still in memory after the destroy.

Comment: If you already unsubscribe than your deduction that the component stays in memory is well founded. Are you using your component as a ionic page by any chance? Ionic does cache those to some degree and provides custom lifecycle methods to handle page entering / leaving. If this is the case you just need to either move the subscribe to somewhere that is only executed once, like ngOnInit or use the ionic lifecycle methods https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle instead of the angular ones.